# How do I get the Coordinates of a shapefile into .csv

Tags: polygon, coordinates

I have followed all the instructions on this site, but my output always shows Area, and Perimeter of each polygon.

Am I missing something? Should I be changing a setting somewhere to select coordinates rather than area/perimeter?

Comment: Polygons don't have single coordinates (nor do lines). Each vertex that makes up the polygon does, or you can get the coordinate of the centroid of the polygon. Are you wanting one coordinate, or a list of coordinates of every vertex per polygon?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using to try and do this, please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with anything but points, you need to convert your shapes to WKT (well known text) columns, and then save that as csv. There is an expression in qgis 2.2 field calculator, it is in a geometry branch, named - geomtoWKT. Haven't tried it. If that doesn't work for you, try searching for other ways to get WKT columns. Just saving layer as csv in qgis has the right dialogs and everything, but for some reason it doesn't create wkt column for me. Maybe try experimenting with that.